# Prove that two subspaces of dimension 3 of a vector space of dimension 5 intersect at non-zero points.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We are given a vector space V of dimension 5

We are given that it has two subspaces U & W, both of dimension 3.

We are to prove that U intersects W at a vector other than 'zero'

My progress

Well, I believe since both of them have dimension 3, their basis must intersect at some point. I just don't understand how to prove it.

Comment: Sorry, it was an error. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $U,W \subseteq V$ intersect as $0$ only. Then the direct sum $U \oplus W$ have dimension $6$. (Try to prove this) But $U \oplus W$ is a vector subspace of $V$, which means its dimension cannot exceed $\dim V$. Threfore $U$ and $W$ must intersect somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ be a basis for $U$.  Let $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ be a basis for $W$.  Then B = $\{u_1, u_2, u_3, w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ spans $U \cup W \subseteq V$.  It cannot be a basis because $\dim V = 5$ so no more than 5 vectors can be linearly independent.  This implies one of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of the other five, which we may arrange as $$
    a u_1 + b u_2 + c u_3 = d w_1 + e w_2 + f w_3
$$ with at least one of $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ equal to $1$, hence not all zero.  This presents a nonzero vector in $U \cap W$, as requested.

Comment: *...spans $U\cup W\subseteq V$...* there is no reason to assume that $U\cup W=V$, but we do know that $U\cup W\subseteq V$.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Meh.  Transmogrified that detail into the version I would make my students work on...  Fixed.